# Calculating "score" based on field selection in DataTables

Tags: datatables, calculated-columns

I'm using DataTables (from datatables.net). I have a created an "Add" option to add entries to my DataTable.

My query is that, if I choose certain options in my form, can I calculate certain scores from it automatically and display in the form.

For example, my form contains the following fields:

```
|Field              Options|
____________________________
|Name Provided?     Yes/No |
|Date Provided?     Yes/No |
|Place Provided?    Yes/No |
```

Assume `Name Provided?` and `Date Provided?` carry 40 points each for selecting `Yes` and `Place Provided?` carries 20 points.

So if a user selects `Yes` for all three then 100 should be displayed dynamically on the form.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Change your query so Yes becomes 1 and No becomes 0, and also replace the questions with their values, then multiply the two columns.

Something like:

```
SELECT field, options
, (CASE field WHEN 'Place Provided?' THEN 20 ELSE 40)
  * (CASE options WHEN 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS 'Score'
FROM your_table
```